# Selecting the First Appearing Child Within the First Element On a Page with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, load, selector

I want to use the `gt()` selector within a `.load()` method. Can this be accomplished?

At the moment, I am seeking a solution which would allow me to apply a `.children(':gt(0)')` selector after `.entry:first` is called.

Here is my progress, so far:

`$("#embed-content").load("https://URL.com/page/ .entry:first .children(':gt(0)')", function(data) {});`

Note, the first element from the load source will not always be a `div`, and will not always contain the same id or class, these aspects will vary.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `:gt(0)`?

Comment: I am trying to select the first child element within the first `.entry` div from the loaded page source. The first child is not uniform, and will vary, hence it will not always be a div.

Comment: `:gt(0)` means "greater than 0," as in, **not** the first. Did you mean first?

Comment: Yes, only the first child element.

Comment: I've updated the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.entry:first .children(':gt(0)')` would be `.entry:first > :gt(0)`. The `>` is the direct child combinator, and then of course `:gt(0)` is "greater than index 0".

I don't think that's what you want though. In a comment you've said:

> I am trying to select the first child element within the first `.entry` div from the loaded page source.

`:gt(0)` will *skip* the first such element, rather than selecting it. To select it you want: `.entry:first > :first`:

```js
$(".entry:first > :first").css({
  color: "green",
  fontWeight: "bold"
});
```

```html
<div class="entry">
  <span>first child of first .entry</span>
  <span>second child of first .entry</span>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <span>first child of second .entry</span>
  <span>second child of second .entry</span>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome, this did the trick! I am not sure how I came around to using `gt()`... In any case, thanks for your help.